# Why does the autocomplete feature from Eclipse ignore my keyboard input?

Tags: debian, eclipse

I installed eclipse via `apt-get` from the Debian repository. My debian is the most current version, 6.

I found that every time I used autocomplete feature from Eclipse, it began to ignore any of my keyboard input until I did a right-click (a menu appears) and a left-click on the source code area. The menu disappears, and the caret goes back to source code area.

I deleted that version of Eclipse, and downloaded one from `eclipse.org` to my desktop folder. Still, it has the same problems.

Does anyone know how to fix this?